# SQL Server 2008 Maintenance Plans -- New DB in Full/Diff Cycle

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2008

I have a MS SQL 2008 database backup maintenance plan that does a Full backup and then two differential backups throughout the day.  If a new database has been created the differential chokes because there is no full to base it off of (at least, this is my guess).

I see that I can manually create a database backup by going to the database and choosing it as a task, but this doesn't auto name it like the plan does and I don't want to mess up the flow of this.  Manually kicking of the Full plan again seems like it is a lot of overhead for a couple of small databases.

What is the typical way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I figured it out:

1. In Management Studio, Go to Management::Maintenance Plans::Full Backups (in my case) and right click that backup task and chose edit.
2. Click view T-SQL , find the relevant backup commands for particular databases
3. Run powershell or cmd.exe and run sqlcmd and connect to the DB.  Then run the backup commands within sqlcmd

Comment: It's a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about the differential is correct, because there's no full backup off the new database.

If I create a new database and there is an existing differential plan as you have, I'd kick off a manual full backup for that new database as a matter of course, just to keep things consistent.

However, you can get creative with scripting out the existing maintenance task, and adding in some error checking to see whether the database has a full backup already, and if not, creating one.

I prefer this route, because you have full control over the script.

EDIT: This [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1877) has some more detail about how to achieve this.

Comment: So when kicking of the full ... how is the naming done to make sure it won't interfere with the current scheduled plan that automatically names them?

Comment: Looking at it now what is throwing me off is that the other databases have the proper destination filled in .. .the new one doesn't have it filled in...

Comment: I've added a link to my answer for you to have a look at.

Comment: Seems like a possible viable long term alternative, but would still like an answer within the scope of the current scheme ...